# Tic Tac Toe with GUI

Tags: java

Okay, I want to create a Tic Tac Toe(X-O) game with GUI, I have drawn it but I'm somehow unable to function it. I do know how to use .addActionListener, and I can set a certain button to "X" or "O", but how do I make it so the first button click turns it to X, the second to O and so on. .addActionListener wont work properly because I have to use it on a certain button, but I don't know which button will be pressed.

Here's the code I've written.

```
public class XO {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame myForm=new JFrame("X-O");
    myForm.setSize(255, 300);
    myForm.setLocation(0, 0);

    JButton []buttons=new JButton[10];
    int x=40, y=0;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        if(i%3==0)
        {
            y+=50; x=40;
        }
        buttons[i]=new JButton((i+1)+"");
        buttons[i].setSize(50, 50);
        buttons[i].setLocation(x, y);
        myForm.add(buttons[i]);
        x+=50;
    }
    buttons[9].setText("Start Over");
    buttons[9].setLocation(80, 205);
    buttons[9].setSize(70, 50);
    buttons[9].setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));

    buttons[0].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        buttons[0].setText("X");
        buttons[0].setForeground(Color.BLUE);
        buttons[0].setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        buttons[0].setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
        buttons[0].setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    myForm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    myForm.setLayout(null);
    myForm.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

As you can see, I will have to use .setActionListener on a specific button, but I dont know which button will be pressed. I hope you get what I mean.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of your main method, you can declare a static counter to determine whose move it is:

```
private static int turnCount = 0;
```

Add the action listeners for each of your buttons within your loop, and determine what to set the button text as based on the counter. Be sure to increment your `turnCount` variable within the action listener:

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    if(i%3==0)
    {
        y+=50; x=40;
    }
    buttons[i]=new JButton((i+1)+"");
    buttons[i].setSize(50, 50);
    buttons[i].setLocation(x, y);

    int butNum = i;
    buttons[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String currentPlayer = turnCount % 2 == 0 ? "X" : "O";
            buttons[butNum].setText(currentPlayer);
            buttons[butNum].setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            buttons[butNum].setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
            buttons[butNum].setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
            buttons[butNum].setEnabled(false);
            turnCount++;
        }
    });

    myForm.add(buttons[i]);
    x+=50;
}
```

Comment: Okay, it works fine but I don't get why I have created butNum and gave it i's value, why does it give an error when I add i in buttons[i], they have the same value.
Also, why do I have to declare turnCount outside of the main, why doesn't it work when I simply do "int turnCount=0; inside the main.

Comment: You cannot use "turnCount" inside the new ActionListener because of scope.  The new ActionListener is a different class and in order to reference "turnCount" the variable needs to either be "final" in the method or be able to to be referred to from the parent class as static because you are in a static method.  Or it could be a member variable if you were in a non-static method and had an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the button that was pressed from the ActionEvent via the `getSource` method - just cast it to a JButton.

```
    for (JButton button : buttons) { // one listener per button
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {    
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JButton button = (JButton)e.getSource(); // which button
                button.setText(getPlayer()); // get X or O
                button.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
                button.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 30));
                button.setMargin(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));
                button.setEnabled(false);
                togglePlayer(); // toggle between X and O
            }
        });
    }
```

I moved the body of your code to a `run` method and added methods to get the player and toggle the player.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    XO game = new XO();
    game.run();
}

private String player = "X";

private String getPlayer() {
    return player;
}

private void togglePlayer() {
    player = "X".equals(player) ? "O" : "X";
}

public void run() {
    JFrame myForm = new JFrame("X-O");
    // rest of your code
    // plus my actionListener changes
    // ...
}
```